Spring boot JPA bulk insert continue after exception
I am trying to do bulk insert using Spring boot JPA. I want the service to continue inserting data and skip the one having exception. I know @Transactional is organic - like ALL or Nothing - but is there any way in Hibernate to achieve this ?
I have added the below properties and this works if there is no exception. However on exception no records are inserted. I would like the success records to be inserted and skip the failed records and if possible hold the failed records in a separate list.
Please see the code below and suggest. Thanks!
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20

    @Transactional(noRollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void addEmployeesInBatch() {
        System.out.println("------------------Batch inserts starts ---------------------");
        List<EmployeeBatch> employeeBatchList = getEmployeesForBatchNew();
        try {
            List<EmployeeBatch> employeesInsertedList = employeeRepositoryBatch.saveAll(employeeBatchList);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            //do nothing
        }
        
    }



the transaction even when you set it no rollback, it will keep all the data but not save them. Just add a little logic here to handle that data.

If your DB support partial insertion then you can try to use entity manager with persistence context. It can looks like so:
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public void bulkInsert(List<EmployeeBatch> employeeBatchList) {
    List<EmployeeBatch> failedEntities = new ArrayList<>();

    for (EmployeeBatch entity : employeeBatchList) {
        try {
            entityManager.persist(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            failedEntities.add(entity);
        }
    }    
}

With this flow you can use failedEntities list for some processing after exception case.
